# Loading dll into running process

Tags: c#, dll, exe, autocad

I'm attempting to build a C# application that opens `acad.exe` using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("acad.exe")` and I'm trying to load a dll `xRef_Tester.dll` into the running process. I've searched around the Microsoft documentation, but I'm somewhat new to C# and microsoft's processes so I haven't had much luck figuring it out. Any help wouldbe greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Does Autocad have an extension point (e.g. plugin infrastructure) that you are trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to plugin a custom dll I built into autocad when it starts up. I found the answer and will be providing it below just for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. I asked someone more skilled with C# and AutoCAD than I am and he pointed me towards the windows registry. I created the link with a `.reg` file and loaded it into the registry. This way the `.dll` plugin will always be loaded when autocad starts up.

http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/09/automatic_loadi.html